# How will i login in when openID goes?

Tags: discussion, login

I login here using OpenID, this will end in February. How do I log in after that?

I can't see a way in the settings how to merge accounts or change login details.

There is no-one to ask either... Any help would be appreciated..

I know this is not strictly a Ubuntu question, but stuck for help..

Thanks

Comment: OpenID is just a protocol. It's MyOpenID, one specific OpenID provider that's going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your profile page click on **my logins** and there you should be able to add new logins.

Comment: Cool... I created a new Stack account.. Thanks